# WCF connection periodically being reset by server

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp

Basically, I am trying to make use of WCF channel to maintain a sticky(don't terminate by FIN or RST flag) TCP connection.

By using ServiePoint class in C#, I can use the ConnectionLeaseTimeout property together with MaxIdleTime to make sure connection will not end by the client.

However, I noticed that every time after the connection becomes idle for ~2 minutes, the server will send an RST flag to terminate it.  I tried to fix it by keep sending the KeepAlive packet from the client, it didn't help. My feeling is that the Reset flag will be sent out regardless of my keepAlive packet. Any thoughts on it?  thanks. The code looks like:

```
    private void SetConnectionIdleTimeSticky(string endpoint)
    {
        var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(endpoint));
        sp.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 10000, 10000);
        sp.MaxIdleTime = 600000;
    }
```

Comment: I tried to set CloseTimeout and ReceiveTimeout in app.config, but it still doesn't help. Any thought on it ?

Comment: was there a workaround or fix found for this problem?